# AVI file header 'file-size' field not matching the actual size of the file

Tags: file-format, avi

Ok so I am currently trying to make an **avi from a set of bitmaps**.
So I popped **open a sample avi file in a hex editor** to check things out. It starts out right with "RIFF". **The next four bytes** represent the **file size**: which i got **"40 6A EA 00"** in HEX. Now this **translates** to 1080748544 in decimal and some **128 MB**. But the file is actaully **just 15 MB**.
 What gives?

Digvijay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha ok, I got the answer. Basically the file size was given in **little endian** format, and hence i was calculating the wrong size.
 **"40 6A EA 00"** does translate to **128 MB**. However **"00 EA 6A 40"***(Where EA is the most significant byte)* does actually come out to about **15 MB**

Digvijay